# How to make UITabBar invisible but still enabled?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The question in title is probably pretty dumb, but i just can't find answer. I need to have invisible UITabBar (without TabBarController) which interacts with user exactly as visible do. If i set its HIDDEN property to YES it becomes disabled even if i leave UserInteractionEnabled checked. Also (since i'm already asking a question) i would like to know what OPAQUE property do. I switch it but nothing seems to be changed and Apple's documentation is not quite understandable for me personally

Comment: opaque means the alpha (= transparency) value of the color isn't considered when the ui element is drawn on the screen. That means everything below an opaque interface element isn't drawn at all. If the color of the ui element has an alpha of 1.0 (= 100% = not transparent at all) you won't see a difference between opaque on or off. But you might see a small performance decrease if you disable opaque in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to have an invisible UITabBar could be to have invisible UIButtons (use the custom type), and use them for your behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the alpha value of your tabbar to 0 it will be transparent.

Comment: but it becomes disabled if i do so

Comment: then set it to 0.02. That works in iOS5 (but might change in the next version because the level when interactions are ignored is an implementation detail) But that's by definition not invisible. Invisible UserInterface elements are usually not very useful. I guess you are doing something weird the could be done in a better way.